# Place a Razor Code inside a JavaScript var

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I wrote a javascript function in which new row gets added in the table. For static data it is working fine, how to place Razor tags inside those javascript var

```
var count = "1";
var strHtml1 ="@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x[count].isChecked)";
count++;
```

This line doesn't seem to work. How should I place the razor code inside the var and also the count [var] inside that razor code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use single quotes

```
var count = "1";
var strHtml1 ='@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x[count].isChecked)';
count++;
```

If it is just the value of checkbox then you can get the value using jquery

```
var count = $('.count:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here your `count` variable is javascript . Can you try to make whole count logic in razor and `strHtml` out like this ?

```
@{
var count = "1";
var strHtml1 =Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x[count].isChecked);
count++;
}
//and in js
var jsStrHmtl='@strHtml1';
```

Comment: exactly what I was about to post.. we've done this before and it worked out fine.